# how to send data from HTML to python and get the result back to HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I know nothing about the interface between HTML and python so I come here to ask for help hope you guys can help me.

HTML are now post on apache server,and I visit this web by the address "http://127.0.0.1/name.html".

Here is what I want to achieve:

There is a form on HTML getting the data,and by clicking the button "submit",the data should be send to python.exe,and the python.exe runs itself and send the result back to HTML(by poping a new dialog).

I searched on the Internet and was wondering will Django help??

Is this even possible?Can anybody help me ?

Comment: What you require is possible. Its better if you learn about django from its documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/. Put some effort before you ask.

Comment: The internet is full of useful resources on this subject, like this one for example: https://pythonschool.net/server-side-scripting/introduction-to-server-side-scripting/ Please put in the effort and use a search engine before asking here. Something like "how to make webpages with python" will turn up a lot of useful results.

Comment: @Ajmal Noushad @ blendenzo I'm sorry it's just because I don't know where to start and I am not sure whether I'm heading toward the right direction that's why I asked here. Next time I will use search engine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After learning about Django,I realised this function by myself.

Here's some suggestions for someone who might have the same problems:

1.Django can help solve this problem:You get the data from HTML,and post/get to a new url;

2.urls.py will control the direction and excute coressponding python program according to the address of the above url mentioned;by doing this you can do some handling with data;

3.use HttpResponse or Render to send back data to HTML from python.

This is just the approximate rout of the whole process and there surely will be some better solutions as long as we keep learning Django and grasp the virtue.